# Need advice on selecting a clustered index for a logging table

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I use SQL Server 2005. I have a simple logging table that my web application uses to track user activities and urls visited.
The table design is very simple

ID (identity value),

LogDate (datetime),

Activity (nvarchar(200)),

Url (nvarchar(1000))

We mainly do Inserts into this table.
Once in a while, our perform some queries against this table if we want to investigate a particular user's activities over a date period.
The table currently has an identity column as its primary key. This is also its clustered index.

I'm wondering if it is better for me to change its clustered index into the LogDate column.
The LogDate column stores the date/time of the activity and can have duplicates, but since we are always inserting into the table, new records should be always at the end of the table, so there is no reason for SQL Server to have to regorganise or do page splits that would impact Insert performance. Having the LogDate column as the clustered index should also help search performance.

Please let me know if my reasoning is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct, provided the rate of inserts is much less than the granularity of `datetime` ([3.33ms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(SQL.90).aspx))

SQL Server 2008 has a new datatype, `DATETIME2`, with higher precision (100 nanoseconds).

If you leave a reasonable amount of free space (FILLFACTOR between 80-90), and rebuild the index regularly (once a week) all should be well.

Answer (score 3):

Before choosing clustering indexes, we need to set priorities. What is more important: speeding up infrequent selects or minimally slowing down frequent inserts? If your inserts are more important, keep the existing clustering index.

Comment: Thanks your advice. This is something that I should also consider.
So, what you're saying is that if I keep the ID as my clustered index, I will get slightly better Insert performance than if I chset the clustered index to LogDate?

Comment: @janemoreno. Yes, because inserting a row with duplicate LogDate will require a uniquifier (if it is clustered on LogDate), it will be somewhat slower.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use the "Database Engine Tuning Wizard".
This will take care of selecting the best choice for your case.
You just need to run it long enough to cover your different cases in order for its analysis to best match your real life case.

You can find more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189303%28SQL.90%29.aspx (for SQL server 2005)

Comment: The DTA does a reasonable job, but it will occasionally suggest the 'wrong' indexes.